# What happened to these question's tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-deletion

Please check this tag [untagged](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). It looks like one of our tag got deleted by mistake. Can we know which tag was deleted and can we restore/recreate the same tag?

Comment: [Noticed the same](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20323691#20323691)

Comment: Yup, that'y I bring it to meta site, since nobody replied you in chat till now.

Answer (score 2):

I talked to one of the Community Managers, and they said there's no way to find out what tag got deleted to make a question untagged, short of using [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org) to find an old version of the question.  Or I suppose we could ask the people who posted the question in the first place.

Note that if a tag is only used in a single question, it will be deleted after 6 months.  You can protect a tag like that from deletion by creating a tag wiki for it.  [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/85848/old-singleton-tags) is a script that will tell you what tags are only used on one question.